# javascript variable returning null

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to build a string of a user's "interests" that they indicate by checking off radio boxes.   When I return the result, there is always an "undefined" prepended to the string of interests.   I know that I can get rid of this issue by initializing var interest as an empty string, like so:

```
var interests ="";
```

But am unsure if this is the proper way to solve the issue.  is there a more optimal data structure for this?

```
        var controlIndex;
        var element;
        var interests;
        var numberOfControls = document.form1.length;

       for (controlIndex = 0; controlIndex < numberOfControls; controlIndex++)

            {
                element = document.form1[controlIndex];
                if (element.type == "radio")
                {
                    if (element.checked == true)
                    {

                     interests += document.form1[controlIndex].value+"\n";


                     console.log(interests);
                     document.getElementById("interests").innerHTML= interests
                    }
                }
            }

        }


    }



<form action="" name="form1">
        <h1>Personal Details</h1>
        Please enter the following details:
        <br>
        <p>
        First Name:
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="txtName"  onchange="txtName_onchange()"/>
        </p>

        <p>
        Age:
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="txtAge" size="3" maxlength="3" onchange="textAge_onblur()" />
        </p>
        <p>
         My interest is:
        <p>Sports
        <input type="radio" name="sports"  value="sports"/>
        </p>
        <p>Politics
        <input type="radio" name="politics" value="politics" />
        </p>
        <p>Magazines
        <input type="radio" name="magazines" value="magazines">
        </p>
        <p>
        <input type="button" value="Submit Registration" name="btnCheckForm"  onclick="btnCheckForm_onclick()" >
        <input type = "button" value = "Clear Details" name="btnClear" onclick="btnClear_onclick()">
        </p>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would turn your "interests" variable into an array.

```
var interests = [];
```

then I would just push into it, like so. When you want to print it out, just join it.

```
             interests.push(document.form1[controlIndex].value);

             console.log(interests.join(""));
```

Comment: The question is whether using `var interests ="";` is a proper way to solve the issue. This answer seems to just reflect your own preference.

Answer (score 2):

> But am unsure if this is the proper way to solve the issue ...

Yes, initialising the variable as a string is the proper way to resolve this issue.

Basically, whenever you initialise your variable like this:

```
var interests;
```

The variable type is implicitly set to `undefined`, so when you apply `+=` onto it, JavaScript changes the type to string with a value of `"undefined"`. Setting the initial value prevents that:

```
var interests = '';
```

Comment: Jack - thanks for your input - seems there are multiple ways to skin a cat…or at least define the undefined ;)

Comment: Yeah; btw, you can change the `.innerHTML` after the loop is done instead of inside each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to put same thing mentioned in above answers in code snippet for better understanding. In my opinion array suits here

```js
function btnCheckForm_onclick (){ 
var controlIndex;
        var element;
        //Case with '' intitlization
        var interests = '';
        
        //Case with [] intitlization
        var interests = [];
        
       var numberOfControls = document.form1.length;

       for (controlIndex = 1; controlIndex < numberOfControls; controlIndex++)

            {
                element = document.form1[controlIndex];
                if (element.type == "radio")
                {
                    if (element.checked == true)
                    {
                     // Case with []
                     //interests.push(document.form1[controlIndex].value);
                     //console.log(interests.join(" "));
                    
                     //Case with ''  
                     interests += document.form1[controlIndex].value+"\n";
                     console.log(interests);
                     
                    }
                }
            }
  
  document.getElementById("interests").innerHTML= interests

}
```

```html
<form action="" name="form1">
        <h1>Personal Details</h1>
        Please enter the following details:
        <br>
        <p>
        First Name:
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="txtName"  onchange="txtName_onchange()"/>
        </p>

        <p>
        Age:
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="txtAge" size="3" maxlength="3" onchange="textAge_onblur()" />
        </p>
        <p>
         My interest is:
        <p>Sports
        <input type="radio" name="sports"  value="sports"/>
        </p>
        <p>Politics
        <input type="radio" name="politics" value="politics" />
        </p>
        <p>Magazines
        <input type="radio" name="magazines" value="magazines">
        </p>
         
        <p>
        <input type="button" value="Submit Registration" name="btnCheckForm"  onclick="btnCheckForm_onclick()" >
        <input type = "button" value = "Clear Details" name="btnClear" onclick="btnClear_onclick()">
        </p>
  
  <div id="interests"></div>
```

Comment: Either way "works" - an array is probably more "elegant' solution

Comment: @JoshKerbel An array makes sense in cases whereby you can benefit from how `Array.join()` works; e.g. insert a newline between every element but not at the start or end.